List of Intel 8086-compatible CPUs?
I'm looking for a good list of CPUs that are compatible with the 8086's architecture(where I can program on those CPUs the same way as I do with the 8086). I would suppose anything that starts with 80 in their name, but I suppose maybe there is an actually useful list?

That would be a huge list. And it will include every model made by Intel, AMD and everyone else that supports the 16-bit programming model, and even future models not even designed yet.

@Justme there could be future models for the 8086 architecture? And why would be there use for something as old as that?

You asked for a list of CPUs compatible with 8086 architecture so you can program it like you would program a 8086. Your current x86 CPU on your desktop or laptop fits that definiton. Or have they somehow removed that x86 comptibility already? I know it will be removed from future CPUs because it's excess clutter nobody uses these days.

I don't think you can run 16-bit code directly on a modern OS. You need an emulator or virtual machine. You can run 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit linux.

@qwr The question was only about list of CPUs. Not how you do that under a modern OS. I just saw an article how they installed DOS natively on the most modern business laptop available so you don't need a modern OS. Or OS at all. If you simply want to execute 8086 code. Of course another problem is, modern macines may not have any of the peripherals like a machine with a 8086 had so the whole platform is different, even if you can still execute 8086 code.

What is your underlying reason for this list? Without spending time to search the web, I'm pretty sure that there is even an open source FPGA implementation, which would provide such hardware for longer than (at least my) life time.

@thebusybee: More than one, as a matter of fact. https://opencores.org/projects/s80186,  https://opencores.org/projects/ao486, https://opencores.org/projects/v586

@LeninYT "why would be there use for something as old as that" - given the high popularity of Book8088 (and Hand386, but that features a CPU with 8086 ISA in a compatibility mode, not the main one), I'd say there is a use...

LeninYT, by 'compatible', do you mean (a) microprocessors that are identical to the 8086, with no more and no less capability than it had except maybe (max clock, clocks/instruction) speed improvements? Or do you mean (b) microprocessors that could natively run 8086 programs but could also have more capabilities? I think you're asking about (b) but want to be certain.

@LeninYT Just to clarify by example; would you count the NEC V30 as 8086 compatible? The Intel 80286 in real mode? The Intel Pentium in real mode? The NEC V60 in emulation mode?

Your deduction about anything beginning with "80" is incorrect. The first three Intel microprocessors following that rule (8008, 8080 and 8085) are not 8086-compatible. An important truth: the 8086 was never intended as a long-term product line, just to keep the company going while the iAPX 432 revolutionised the computer industry. If you've never heard of that CPU, that's about how successful it was. Itanium was less of a failure than iAPX 432.

Do emulations count as well? If so, then you can also include stuff like PCjs, DOSBox-X and all the other software emulators that exist as well.

@ErikF, how could an emulator be a microprocessor, though? One's a computer program, the other's a chip with pins.

How would your program know the difference between a perfect emulator and a physical chip?

@ErikF, however the question clearly asks "I'm looking for a good list of CPUs", and a CPU (by which they mean microprocessor, which the 8086 is) doesn't include computer emulations, it means an IC. It's the specific question asked, let's not head off up some 'does Deckard know he's a replicant' avenue about emulation...

Well, there are many lists, just take a look at Wikipedia, which offers for example

List of all Intel CPU
List of all AMD CPU

While they also include some non x86, the majority in both are 8086 compatible. And And they are huge - despite not really listing all variations there are/were. Of course there were many other producers of 8086 compatible CPUs. Some licenced or clones, other new designs with enhancements. A hint can be seen in the

List of x86 Manufacturers

Seeing this, brings the important question, what is that you want to gain from that list and wo what depth it needs to list variations. Do you care for

a granularity as fine as power level, package and pinout?
Or do you need to know all machine specific details like configuration registers?
Or is it about all extensions to the basic 8086 visible to user code?
Or 'just' the basic mainstream families with their common extensions?

While the first may include tens of thousands of variants, many not technical at all but marketing related, the last is nicely described in those many articles about x86 architecture and it's development. Like Wikipedia's

x86 article.

That topic is as well filled to the brim in other language edition and across the web. So it might be a good idea to think what the real need is you want to have fulfilled. Once done modify the question, or write a new, more focused one. Although I would imagine you find it self answering once you reached that point :)
